# Scilab WScilex.exe process

Tags: process, scilab

Whenever I quit Scilab, the WScilex.exe process keeps running and I have to terminate it in the task manager. Is there a way to fix this ?

I'm running Scilab 5.5.0 on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1.